# Modulo Quadratic Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

Can you, given a large number N, find a, b, c such that ax^2 + bx + c = 0 has at least N roots? All of this is in any mod you choose.

Comment: You could pick for instance $a=0, b=2^{N}, c=0$ with mod $2^{N+1}$. It has $2^N>N$ roots.

Comment: @IlikeSerena In answering questions of quadratic type, setting ((x^2)) to 0 is a bit unfair.

Comment: @Mick: Fair enough, but a similar, admittedly somewhat trivial, solution applies with $a=1$. Perhaps the problem becomes more interesting if we require $a$ and $c$ to be non-zero.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Agree that non-zero "a" (and also "c") situations are  more interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $N$, the congruence $x^2\equiv0\pmod{N^2}$ has the $N$ solutions $0,N,2N,\dots,(N-1)N$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Given $N$, pick any number $a>N$, and you get more than $N$ roots modulo $a^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I was experimenting with mods that were multiples of 10 (this question was a spinoff of another one and for that I used multiples of 10). The only problem was that I couldn't find a good correlation between the mods and the amount of roots. Thanks for your help @Gerry Myerson

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to the answer. If my answer doesn't satisfy you, maybe you can edit your question so people can know what remains to be done.